# Flutter App links and universal links are now working?

Tags: flutter, app-store, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, applinks

I am learning flutter and want to apply the app links and universal links functionality in the app but wondering some issues.

I want to implement this functionality with the help of my domain.

- I want to open a screen(details) in my app and i am handling using the [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/versions).

For that the url is :
https://example.com/shared/?askdjfhj=aakjsndfkaj

for Android app links I have added the assetlinks.json and for ios (apple-app-site-association), into the domain's home directory like this:

Android: https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
IOS: https://example.com//.well-known/apple-app-site-association

The link > **https://example.com/shared/?askdjfhj=aakjsndfkaj** , is working fine for android only when clicking from emails and messages but not if I hit this url into the chrome browser.

And this url is not working for ios in any case like from emails and messages as well as.

What I want to achieve?
It should be like, if app is installed then redirect to the particular screen. If not installed then redirect to corresponding Store like Play/App store to install it.

Any can help me to figure out which step I skipped, thanks.

Comment: check the readme of the package you using. it consists of all required steps to be taken before using for both Android and iOS. Make sure you have done all of it.

Comment: I have configured those, but still facing an issue.

Comment: It takes around 24 hours to pickup the wellknown file by Apple servers. If it hasn’t been 24 hours, open the file on browser in ios and wait.

Comment: Thanks for giving me patience but already 5 days gone.

Comment: did you set FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled key in Info.plist? If you are using unilinks you should remove it.

Comment: Also make sure the association file contents are proper .. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links